# Dropdown Select with Multiselect in Kendo-ui

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

Does anyone know if there is a multi-select for kendo UI like the ones we have for Angular Material?

I looked up some of the Kendo controls and all I have is `multiselect` with keyword select. Not the ones I need.

This is what I exactly need:

[[image: What I need]

but this is what I see:

[image: what I see]

Comment: Your excepted control name is dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box: their drop down is a DropDownList which is designed for single selection.

Here are discussions on solutions and their limitations:

1. https://www.telerik.com/forums/dropdownlist-with-multi-select
2. https://www.telerik.com/forums/multiselect-with-checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Kendo Multiselect](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/multiselect/) for multi select dropdown with few customization.

Add `kendoMultiSelectSummaryTag` attribute in `<kendo-multiselect>`.

**Stackblitz Demo :** [Kendo Multiselect Dropdown](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rrnyvn?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: can you how can i add select all option for this multi select sample .

Answer (score 0):

**itemTemplate** works for this issue. Here is my solution.

```js
let $selectHtml = $(`<select class="multi-select-items" multiple="multiple" /></select>`);

const checkInputs = (elements) => {
    elements.each(index => {
        const element = $(elements[index]);
        const input = element.children("input");
        input.prop("checked", element.hasClass("k-state-selected"));
    });
};
const options = {
    itemTemplate: "<input type='checkbox'/> #:data.text#",
    autoClose: false,
    downArrow: true,
    dataBound: function() {
        var items = this.ul.find("li");
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            checkInputs(items);
        });
    },
    change: function() {
        var items = this.ul.find("li");
        checkInputs(items);
    },
    height: 150
};

$selectHtml.kendoMultiSelect(options);
```

[Show ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kz5VR.png)

Comment: Kendo version: 2021.2.616